# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.At ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am facing issue due to the error i.e

> Can't set headers after they are sent

Actually, I am querying on my MongoDB like this.

```
Test.aggregate([
                {$match: {'ownerid': req.body.ownerid}},
                {$unwind: '$groupname'},
                {$project: {_id:1, groupname :"$groupname",}}
            ], function(error, data){
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    //It will return Two group id.
                    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

                        //These are the variables for my custom function which can update my query on another table
                        var primaryfilter = {'userid': req.body.ownerid};
                        var secondaryfilter = { "groupowned" : { 'groupid': data[i]._id, 'groupname': data[i].groupname } };
                        var activityname = 'Group Owned';
                        updater(req, res, Test1, primaryfilter, secondaryfilter, activityname);
                    }
                }
            });
```

This One is My updater Function:

```
var updater = function(req, res, CollectionName, primaryfilter, secondaryfilter, activityname){
    CollectionName.update(primaryfilter, {$push: secondaryfilter}, function(error2, result){
        if (error2) {
            res.send({"error":"true", "status":"500", "message":"Oops! Some error occurred while updating the "+activityname+" on Post"});
        } else {
            res.send({"error":"false", "status":"201", "message":"Successfully Updated "+activityname+" on Post"});
        }
    });

};
```

Actually, I want to fetch group id from test collection and update all these Ids on my secondary table i.e Test1
I know this error Generates Due to loop. Anyone Suggest me that how I can solve this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: why don't you call res.send after the for loop??

Comment: Because I have to update one by one entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you see is caused when you try to send more than one response for a given request.

You're calling `res.send()` from with in `updater()`.  And, you're calling `updater()` from within a `for` loop which means you're calling it multiple times.

So, you end up calling `res.send()` more than once on the same request.  That is what causes the error you see.  You can only call `res.send()` once per request.

Probably what you need to do is to accumulate results from all your `.update()` calls and then send one response when they are all done.  But, you have to decide what you want the behavior to be.  What kind of response to you want to send?  An array of objects like this?

```
{"error":"false", "status":"201", "message":"Successfully Updated "+activityname+" on Post"}
```

Or something else?  And, what do you want the response to be if one of your requests gets an error?

Since this is mongodb, you'll probably want to use the promises built-in to mongodb with `Promise.all()` to know when all the `.update()` calls are done.

Here's one way to approach it:

```
Test.aggregate([
    {$match: {'ownerid': req.body.ownerid}},
    {$unwind: '$groupname'},
    {$project: {_id:1, groupname :"$groupname",}}
], function(error, data){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        //It will return Two group id.
        let promises = [];
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

            //These are the variables for my custom function which can update my query on another table
            var primaryfilter = {'userid': req.body.ownerid};
            var secondaryfilter = { "groupowned" : { 'groupid': data[i]._id, 'groupname': data[i].groupname } };
            var activityname = 'Group Owned';
            promises.push(updater(Test1, primaryfilter, secondaryfilter, activityname));
        }
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
            res.json(results);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        })
    }
});


function updater(CollectionName, primaryfilter, secondaryfilter, activityname){
    return CollectionName.update(primaryfilter, {$push: secondaryfilter}).then(function(result) {
        return {"error":"false", "status":"201", "message":"Successfully Updated "+activityname+" on Post"};
    }).catch(function(err) {
        return {"error":"true", "status":"500", "message":"Oops! Some error occurred while updating the "+activityname+" on Post"};
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is caused when you try to send more than one response to a given request. Try this code :

```
const async = require('async'); // async node module : npm install --save async

        Test.aggregate([
            {$match: {'ownerid': req.body.ownerid}},
            {$unwind: '$groupname'},
            {$project: {_id:1, groupname :"$groupname"}}
        ], function(error, data){
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                //Use async module instead of simple javascript loop
                var primaryfilter = {'userid': req.body.ownerid};
                var activityname = 'Group Owned';
                async.eachSeries(data, function(dataItem, asyncCallback){

                    var secondaryfilter = { "groupowned" : { 'groupid': dataItem._id, 'groupname': dataItem.groupname } };

                    Test1.update(primaryfilter, {$push: secondaryfilter}, function(error, result){
                        if (error) {
                            asyncCallback(error);
                        } else {
                            asyncCallback();
                        }
                    });

                }, function(err){
                    if(err) {
                        return res.send({"error":"true", "status":"500", "message":"Oops! Some error occurred while updating the "+activityname+" on Post"});
                    }
                    return res.send({"error":"false", "status":"201", "message":"Successfully Updated "+activityname+" on Post"});
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Really Appreciating you Mr. Krishan Kant Sharma for your Support